# How to force tabs opened from bookmark folders to load content before being viewed?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks, browser-tabs

I use Firefox. I have certain pages that I check every day grouped into a bookmarks folder. Previously I could middle-click this folder and have all pages open in tabs. This still occurs, but the content of those tabs no longer loads until I actually visit the tab. Since I am going to be visiting those tabs within a few minutes anyway, keeping content in those tabs unloaded is not desirable.

However, I have no use for a solution that also causes all tabs to load upon session restore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tab Mix Plus is a Firefox extension that can do what you request, though it may be overkill, because of the many other options. My favorite one is auto-raise: mouse-over (hover) on a tab to select it.

Tab Mix Plus is Electrolysis (multi-process) compatible.

[image: Settings for tab opening in Tab Mix Plus]

Comment: I have that extension actually. This seems to be on the right track. Unintuitively, it seems that this issue is caused by having "Load tabs progressively" checked, not "Don't load tabs until selected".

I am a bit concerned that unchecking this will lead to loading all tabs on restarting the browser, though.